# Microsoft Graph to access and modify application object in Azure AD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I would like to know if it is possible to use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph APIs to create and modify Application objects in AAD.
In particular I'm interested in updating permissions to the newly created app. Currently I'm using the following powershell script to add a permission to the app object

```
$url = "https://graph.windows.net/$tentant_id/applications/$($ad_app.ObjectID)?api-version=1.6"
$postData = "{`"requiredResourceAccess`":[{`"resourceAppId`":`"00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`",`"resourceAccess`":[{`"id`":`"311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6`",`"type`":`"Scope`"}]}]}"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method "PATCH" -Headers $authHeader -Body $postData
```

How do I achieve the same with "https://graph.microsoft.com" endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

The beta endpoint has the [application resource type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/application) with which you can [create new applications](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_applications), and [modify](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_update) them.